# Realtime form - on submit clear textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, real-time

I have been looking through StackOverflow a lot and found SOME solutions but they don't work for me :( Probably because I can't place the strings of code correctly.

I have a form which submits content to a database - and a script that loads the database inputs into a div below the form. It works realtime with a small delay.

```
<div id="addCommentContainer">

<form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->display_username; ?>"  id="name" />
        
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->email; ?>"  id="email" />
        
        <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        
        <input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

It works. I also have this script:
http://sandbox.jinoh.dk/script.js

I tried a solution onclick - but it made the content disappear not being posted. I tried onsubmit - but it didn't work. What I want is the "comment" to be posted and then disappear from the form aka the form to be cleared.

Chatchatchat-div is the one that the comments are loaded into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){
  var form = this;
  .....
  ....

  $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
    if(msg.status){
      form.reset(); // if you want to reset on msg status
    }
    ....                
  });

  this.reset(); // just reset the form what happen
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I see the logic in it :)